# How to handle mouse-over using selenium RC with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I am trying to automate eCommerce website and i have a problem how to work with mouseover in selenium RC.

Take a look on scenario below.

1. Visit angara.com
2. Go to header menu and mouse-over on "RINGS" and click on "Blue Sapphire" in Shop by stone Section.

I have stuck on point no. 2.Below is the code which i have written for the above.

public void angara_product(){

```
    Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("QAvinod", 4444, "*firefox",
            "http://www.angara.com");
    selenium.start();
    selenium.open("/");
                selenium.click("xpath=/html/body/div[5]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/a/img");
    selenium.mouseOver("xpath=//li[@class='first-nav']/a/@href");
    selenium.click("xpath=//a[text()='Blue Sapphire']/@href");
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is a very awkward way to use selenium, you should use a `WebDriver` to find and define `WebElement` objects hopefully by their IDs and not a full xPath traversal through the DOM. Also would help if you'd describe what exactly doesn't work for you.

Comment: Ceiling Gecko, I want this script should be written in selenium RC.selenium.mouseOver("xpath=//li[@class='first-nav']/a/@href");
    selenium.click("xpath=//a[text()='Blue Sapphire']/@href"); above 2 commands are not working for me.

Comment: What happens if you supply the xpath without the `@href` e.g. `selenium.click("xpath=//a[text()='Blue Sapphire']");`

Comment: Ceiling, Can you please write the script in selenium rc for the above scenario.